# unable to mock TextMessage

Tags: mockito, powermock

Could some one help me how to mock this line, i tried and getting null pointer exception

```
mockTextMessage = mock(TextMessage.class);
when(mockTextMessage.getText()).thenReturn(any(String.class));


public void onMessage(Message message) {
    String text = ((TextMessage)message).getText();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass actual object in `thenReturn()`  method.

See the below definition of `thenReturn(T value)`

> Sets a return value to be returned when the method is called.
>       "When the x method is called then return y".

**Examples**

```
when(mock.x()).thenReturn(y); 
when(mock.someMethod()).thenReturn(10);
```

In your case, pass the actual string value that you wanted to be returned when getText() method is called on mockTextMessage.

```
when(mockTextMessage.getText()).thenReturn("expected value");
```